# Is it a good idea to use static type?

Tags: java

I know the difference between static type and other types but I am not sure which is to used where. Now I am using static types in all places to avoid object instantiation. Is it a good idea to use it that way ? Is there any particular disadvantage in using static type in all places ??

EDIT

What do you call this as `static String staff` ?

Comment: Java doesn't have anything called a "static type". Do you mean *static inner classes*? Could you give a code example?

Comment: Java is an 'Object' Oriented language.  The ability to instantiate an object is there because that is a good pattern.  Static objects/methods have their place, too, of course.  If the question is just whether you should use objects sometimes, then the answer is 'Yes.'

check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns for some examples...

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: check my edit.

Comment: That is a *static member* (assuming that's a member of a class). Using a static member does not "avoid object instantiation", rather it has quite a different meaning from using a non-static member. See the answers below for more detail.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Yes i understood that quoted part now!! thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an excellent question.  Usually you should **not** use `static` methods/variables unless you know for sure that it's a correct application for it.  In object oriented programming (OOP), objects encapsulate data and behavior.  Typically, *instance methods are used to manipulate the object's data.

`Static` methods/variables should only be used for functionality that is not associated with any particular object.  A good example of a valid application for `static` is [`Math.random()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29).

Some notes about instance and static methods/variables:

- Instance variables have access to static *and* instance variables/methods, but static methods can only access other static variables/methods.
- A static variable will always be the same across all instances of a class.

A good book to read that covers this topic is [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by Robert Martin.  Highly recommended.

*instance methods are the opposite of static methods.  They are associated with a class instance, instead of the class itself.

---

Addressing your edit, assuming that that's a variable, you'd access it like this:

```
MyClass.staff = "bob, george, and linda";
System.out.println(MyClass.staff);
```

---

Edit: here's a post I made on another forum a while back, with some good answers.  It's a PHP forum, but the concepts still apply.

http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=127667

Comment: @Jonah: so its fine to use static methods/variables if i have to share the variables throughout the application rite ?

Comment: @Deepak: using it like that makes it what is called a "global variable".  Most of the time there are better ways to share an object across your application than global variables.

Comment: @Jonah: I am pretty clear on how to use static methods/variables but i just wanted to know if it is a sin to use often :)

Comment: @Deepak: It only a sin if it's actually a sin.  If it's the correct way to handle a problem, then do it.  Perhaps if you have specifics you could ask a new question to find out if it's best to throw static methods at a particular problem.

Comment: @Jonah: Now your posts on that php forum introduces me a new term 'dependency injection'. I would like to do more research on that now!!

Comment: @Jonah: 'It only a sin if it's actually a sin' I understood that!!

Answer (score 1):

When there are multiple instances of an object, static-typed variables and functions are shared across all instances.

Answer (score 0):

Most logic  in any application will be modularized, and will operate on some shared fields. This is the reason why most methods are non-static. The 'fields' in this case can be something as basic as 'firstName', etc. But in other cases, the 'fields' are instances of other classes such as DataAccess (DAO) classes.

Variables i.e. fields should almost never be static, unless they are 'constants'.

A good example where you will be use static methods is a class that transforms Strings, for example:

```
public class StringUtil{

  public static String convertToHex(String orig){

  }
}
```